# Using PHP and MySQL, how can I create a simple room availability check?

Tags: php, mysql

What is a simple way to check for room availability?

I have been working on a little project for class, just a simple, small hotel registration page that needs contact information and billing information.  Bear in mind that unencrypted information is not an issue here.

Here is part of my process.php page:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO UMBRELLA (firstName, lastName, email, arrivalDate, 
departureDate, adultGuests, childGuests, roomReservation, newsletterBool, 
comments, creditCardType, creditCardNumber, expirationMonth, expirationYear, 
securityCode, phone)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[lastName]','$_POST[email]', '$_POST[arrivalDate]', 
'$_POST[departureDate]', '$_POST[adultGuests]', '$_POST[childGuests]', 
'$_POST[roomReservation]', '$_POST[newsletterBool]', '$_POST[comments]',
'$_POST[creditCardType]', '$_POST[creditCardNumber]', '$_POST[expirationMonth]', 
'$_POST[expirationYear]', '$_POST[securityCode]', '$_POST[phone]')";
```

I would prefer to keep the solution simple, as it's only a minor requirement, so I don't want to create additional tables for a many-to-many relationship (e.g. ROOMS table, BOOKINGS table).  The roomReservation value only has three options:  1.  Presidential Suite  2.  Master Suite  3.  Standard Suite.  Basically, I would like to create a variable, $maxRooms, that is equal to 10.

```
$maxRooms=10;
```

I would then use a SELECT statement to get all useful data for each specific room type (note this is pseudocode so some formatting might be off):

```
$standard = "SELECT arrivalDate, departureDate, roomReservation FROM UMBRELLA 
WHERE roomReservation = 'Standard Suite';"

$master = "SELECT arrivalDate, departureDate, roomReservation FROM UMBRELLA 
WHERE roomReservation = 'Master Suite';"

$presidential = "SELECT arrivalDate, departureDate, roomReservation FROM 
UMBRELLA WHERE roomReservation = 'Presidential Suite';"
```

I would then check how many rooms are reserved in a given date range, and if it was >=maxRooms then the page would output an error.  This is the part I'm having trouble on.  I would appreciate any help or insight!  Thank you!

tl;dr  What code do I need to compare the $standard, $master, and $presidential variables to a given date range?

Comment: Don't *ever* build SQL from raw $_POST vars like that.  It's *really* bad.  Doesn't matter if it's "internal only" - one day someone will (even accidentally) [put something in that will blow up your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Your SQL is far too open to injection. Please see PDO or at least `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Good point, everyone.  I was really unsure of that part, so it was just pseudo-code.  I have actually used mysql_real_escape_string() before, so if I do implement this approach I will certainly use it.

Comment: how you are storing the dates in the database it's a proper date formate or varchar formate.

Comment: think of the children.  please use PDO and parameters for your queries.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314324/mysqli-php-common-class/8318720#8318720)

Comment: A credit card security code should **never** under **any** circumstances be stored in whole or in part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, they will be telling you which type of room they would like through something like a select input?
ie:

```
    <select>
        <option value="presidential">Presidential Suite</option>
        ....</select>
```

The max rooms: Does that refer to there being 10 master suites, 10 standard suites, and 10 presidential suites for a total of 30 rooms in all? If not, and it's only 10 rooms in the whole 'hotel' how are the distributed across the three types? Also, I'm assuming you would not like the database to upload the new reservation if the rooms are full.

```
    $maxRooms = 10;
    $fetchQuery = "SELECT room_reservation FROM UMBRELLA 
              WHERE room_reservation = '$_POST[roomReservation]'";
    $fetchResult = mysql_query($fetchQuery);
    $numberRooms = mysql_num_rows($fetchResult);
        if($numberRooms >= $maxRooms)
        {
            echo "error: All ".$_POST['roomReservation'."s are currently booked.";
        }
        else
        {
            $insertQuery = "INSERT into UMBRELLA VALUES('$_POST[firstname]',.....)";
            mysql_query($insertQuery) or die(mysql_error());                        
            echo "Registration Complete.";
        }
```

So, when someone clicks "Make Reservation" or whatever your submit button on the form is called, this checks to ensure the room type they have chosen is available. If it's not they are they are all booked. If there are open rooms of the type they chose, they are reserved the room (which adds to the current number of rooms reserved of that type making it one less for the next) etc. You'd have to write something for checking out etc obviously.

Something like this? Honestly, I haven't tried it etc...but is this the idea you are going for? I hope it helps a bit maybe...

Comment: This is not validating anything..you would need to do that. I used post simply for ease of viewing..please validate etc etc etc et cetc etlsfj;lafj

Comment: Yes, I used a drop-down box for the room selection.  Also, there are 10 rooms of each type.  Lastly, you are correct--I would like to output an error message and not upload any information if the rooms of that type are full.  You are spot on, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take for example the Standard Suit query, and you can use the same idea for the rest two.

To find how many reservations exist for a given date range, this query should do the trick:

```
$reservations = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM UMBRELLA 
WHERE roomReservation = 'Standard Suite' AND arrivalDate BETWEEN '2011-11-20' AND '2011-11-30'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to reiterate, but obviously you do not want to pass the `$_POST` values directly into your data tier in any case.  Also, you should never be saving fields like `CreditCardNumber` on any server that hasn't undergone a PCI compliance evaluation.  I realize this is a theoretical application for class, but these things need to be noted for those who might stumble in.

That said, the object to use for your conditional comparison is the `DateTime` object in PHP5, which is represented in PHP4 using the `date` suite of functions.

I realize you mention wanting to avoid joins, but joining across tables storing transaction data and room availability separately might make this even simpler.  It may be worth considering.

So that said, here's the kind of query you'll need to be doing, if I have understood your needs correctly.

```
//We need to find the no more than ten rooms have been reserved in a given date range, let's //say for argument sake, 10 days.

$now = DateTime();
$inc = DateInterval::createFromDateString('-10 days');
$past = $now->add($inc);
```

This sets up objects storing dates ten days in the past from now.  So your queries are then adjusted to find counts instead, and only in a specific date range.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rooms FROM UMBRELLA WHERE roomReservation='Standard Suite' AND arrivalDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

You'd then use your sql drivers to pass in the two values of the date time objects, using `$past->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` and `$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` for your between values. Repeat this process for your other two room types.

You can then conditionally check the values for these three counts against your max rooms and adjust the behavior of the application to suit.